# This change context and it's undefined angularjs

Tags: angularjs, scope, this

I have function like below, and I have problem because of `this` context. When I run my code, I have error in my console: `Cannot set property 'cat' of undefined` 
When I change `this.cat` for `$scope.cat`, everything is fine.  I tried add $scope.apply and timeout, but it doesn't works. It seems like this change context, but I dont't know how to repair it.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('test.module')
      .component('testComponent', {
        bindings: {},
        templateUrl: 'js/modules/test/test.html',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        controller: (TestService, $scope) => {  

          TestService.changed(() => {
            const testValue = test.findById(id)

            if (testValue && testValue.data) {
              this.cat = testValue.data
            }
          })
       }
    })
  })()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using [arrowFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) as the controller, so, the `this` in that case would be the IFFE function that wraps the entire code.

You will need to change the arrowFunction to regular one, that will create a separate `this` context for it.

```
(function() {
  angular.module('test.module')
    .component('testComponent', {
      bindings: {},
      templateUrl: 'js/modules/test/test.html',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      controller: function(TestService, $scope) {

        TestService.changed(() => {
          const testValue = test.findById(id)

          if (testValue && testValue.data) {
            this.cat = testValue.data
          }
        })
      }
    })
})()
```